# Poorly initialized target critic

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

What is a good way to handle the first round of off policy training with Deep Deterministic Policy Gradients?

Here is my problem: I initialize all weights with [Xavier Initialization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/xavier_initializer) and zeros for bias. However when computing the critic loss I'm getting an infinite MSE since the difference between `Q_target` and `Q_eval` is so large. Is it a bad idea to just clip this to a very large value?

```
Q_target_i = r_i + discount * Q_target(i+1)
critic_loss = MSE(Q_target_i, Q_eval_i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by initializing the evaluation networks to be the same as the target networks.